# Input HDMI signal computer to be usable by applications inside

Tags: hdmi, usb-c, display-adapter

I wonder if there already exists a solution which allows you to connect an HDMI-cable (outputting information) to an adapter, hook it up to a laptop (possibly via USB-C?) and then access the HDMI information in the OS.

The dream scenario would be having the HDMI input appear inside a simple window in the OS on the laptop. Graph below.

[image]

Comment: There are video capture cards with HDMI input for desktops, I don't know about laptops. I think what you want isn't feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDMI capture devices do exist and they can be connected to a PC with various interfaces. But HDCP protected content cannot be captured so this will limit what content will be available for display.